# Automatically generated region certificate in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

In Azure portal when I get the list of all resource I can see a machine-generated resource of type Microsoft.Web/certificates which I (as Admin) cant view the details. At what point does this resource gets created and is this region specific? The reason I ask about the region is that its name contains the name of the region itself. If that is region specific then I should have two of these automatically generated certificates because I have resources in two region. Could this resource have been generated by visual studio publishing tool? How can I know more about this resource?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the activity log to find out everything that happens with your subscription:

[image: Azure Activity Log]

You can use filters and you can **who** did **what** and **when** he did it. This is not limited to authenticated users, but also automated scripts with service principals.

P.S. Activity Logs is located under "More Services", it is not part of "All Resources".

Answer (score 0):

> In Azure portal when I get the list of all resource I can see a machine-generated resource of type Microsoft.Web/certificates which I (as Admin) cant view the details. At what point does this resource gets created and is this region specific?

As far as I know, when you upload a SSL certificate you purchased externally to an Azure Web App successfully, then a resource of type Microsoft.Web/certificates would be generated automatically in the same resource group as your Web App. And the name of this machine-generated resource consists of the thumbprint of the certificate you uploaded and the location of your Web App.

As astaykov said, you could find detailed operations by searching Activity Log. Here is a snapshot on my side, you could refer to it.

[image]
[image]